# How to set control x:Uid attribute programmatically for a metro app control?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I need to set the x:Uid attribute of some control programmatically? this attribute is used for localization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not really strong on this subject but if we are talking about the same thing, as you can see here: [BamlLocalizableResourceKey.Uid Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.localizer.bamllocalizableresourcekey.uid.aspx)

the public property has only a get, so you can't change it easily from C# code.

```
public string Uid { get; }
```

see more [x:Uid Directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613571.aspx) to find out that this property is set as directive and not like other attributes in XAML.

Comment: In WPF each UIElement has Uid property, so it is not a problem for WPF.