# How to use x:Uid in windows phone 8?

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-phone-8

We can use x:Uid in windows-8 as

Where in `.resw` I have define
`mainTitle.Text = "Your Name"`

In this way `TextBlock`'s text becomes `Your Name`.

How can I achieve the same in windows phone 8?

When I put `mainTitle.Text` in `.resx` it gives error.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15887843/how-to-set-control-xuid-attribute-programmatically-for-a-metro-app-control

Comment: @Xyroid I'm looking for windows phone 8 and that question is for windows-8

Comment: I don't think, it would be available as Windows phone 8 and Windows 8 frameworks are quite similar

Comment: Windows Phone 8 doesn't support the element property syntax for naming resources. "mainTitle.Text" should be "mainTitle" in your resource file

Comment: @kindasimple can you show me how to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use binding here

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.ApplicationTitle, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"/>
```

For more about localization read [How to build a localized app for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/ff637520%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

And to know about x:Uid read [x:Uid Directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613571.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You have to use binding in Windows Phone 8.

The most simple way to see this in action is to create a new project and take a look at MainPage.xaml.  The binding is demonstrated in the following comment

For example:

```
Text="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.ApplicationTitle, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"
```

To localize some text, you bind the LocalizedStrings class (created with the project) which wraps your static Resource file.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.ApplicationTitle, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" />
```

The LocalizedStrings resource is already there in your App.xaml

```
<local:LocalizedStrings x:Key="LocalizedStrings"/>
```

Comment: It's a good answer.. Will accept it if I couldn't find `x:Uid`. One more question as I see I can use `x:Uid` in wp8 so if it doesn't work in wp8 then why it's there?

Comment: I can only suppose that support is coming in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Binding is one solution but simply you can do the following.
If you have the following AppBarButton

```
            <AppBarButton 
                Name="AppBarButtonMore" 
                x:Uid="appbar_more_title"
                Click="AppBarButtonMore_Click"/>
```

add the string file with the key `appbar_more_title.Label` to your resources and your button will take  that string as label property.This is also valid for any UI controls.